# can I add if...else in TensorFlow custom layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to compose custom layers with if...else loop, then calculate the gradients against some special layers weights. How to do that?

we can compose custom layers with following method(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers)

```
class ResnetIdentityBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(ResnetIdentityBlock, self).__init__(name='')
    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters

    self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1))
    self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding='same')
    self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()



  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
    x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.conv2b(x)
    x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)   

    x += input_tensor
    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```

can I use following method?

```
class ResnetIdentityBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(ResnetIdentityBlock, self).__init__(name='')
    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters

    if trk=='rnn' and req==True:
        self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1))
        self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    if trk=!'rnn' and inf==True:
        self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()



  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    if trk=='rnn' and req==True:
        x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    if trk=!'rnn' and inf==True:
        x = self.conv2b(x)
        x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)   

    x += input_tensor
    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```

If I can, how to calculate the gradients against some special layers weights?eg. self.conv2b? If I want to calculate the gradients with following method, how to change model.trainable_variables?

```
model=ResnetIdentityBlock()

def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

Comment: Looks like [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#privileged_training_argument_in_the_call_method) from the official docs uses the `if` statement in `call`. I'm not sure how it affects serialization. I've been passing custom layers in the `custom_objects` when loading from `.h5` files at runtime... so it sounds like the layers must have their behavior determined at runtime.